# Run Python, Anaconda, Pandas, Numpy offline on a Server getting dependency error

Tags: pandas, virtual-machine, offline

After installing Anaconda on a Virtual Machine I run a script which is working on my local machine but not on my Virtual Machine.

I'm getting the error Message:

```
C:\Users\...\python>"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\...\reporting.py"
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:140: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\reporting.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.18.5"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.
```

The VM has no Internet. Is there any way to install all the required libs and frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can package your script and used libraries using something like [Pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/). When you use an virtualenv keep in mind that all the packages that you use during pyinstaller execution are stored and may lead to an huge .exe

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i installed pyinstaller and compiled an .exe. However on the VM it is showing an error for a millisecond. This way i cannot resolve what the issue is :S

Comment: You can catch the exception by using `try` and `except` and write the error message to an errorfile. Or you can record your display with e.g. VLC Player to see the Error :D

Comment: Addition: Or run your exe in cmd. Then the error is shown without closing the window.